# How to run gdcm examples in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, compilation, dicom, gdcm

I am trying to run this simple example in GDCM. I have installed the library c++ version and the installation works perfectly fine but I am not able to figure out how to compile and run a example.

```
#include "gdcmReader.h"
#include "gdcmWriter.h"
#include "gdcmAttribute.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if( argc < 3 )
    {
    std::cerr << argv[0] << " input.dcm output.dcm" << std::endl;
    return 1;
    }
  const char *filename = argv[1];
  const char *outfilename = argv[2];

  // Instanciate the reader:
  gdcm::Reader reader;
  reader.SetFileName( filename );
  if( !reader.Read() )
    {
    std::cerr << "Could not read: " << filename << std::endl;
    return 1;
    }

  // If we reach here, we know for sure only 1 thing:
  // It is a valid DICOM file (potentially an old ACR-NEMA 1.0/2.0 file)
  // (Maybe, it's NOT a Dicom image -could be a DICOMDIR, a RTSTRUCT, etc-)

  // The output of gdcm::Reader is a gdcm::File
  gdcm::File &file = reader.GetFile();

  // the dataset is the the set of element we are interested in:
  gdcm::DataSet &ds = file.GetDataSet();

  // Contruct a static(*) type for Image Comments :
  gdcm::Attribute<0x0020,0x4000> imagecomments;
  imagecomments.SetValue( "Hello, World !" );

  // Now replace the Image Comments from the dataset with our:
  ds.Replace( imagecomments.GetAsDataElement() );

  // Write the modified DataSet back to disk
  gdcm::Writer writer;
  writer.CheckFileMetaInformationOff(); // Do not attempt to reconstruct the file meta to preserve the file
                                        // as close to the original as possible.
  writer.SetFileName( outfilename );
  writer.SetFile( file );
  if( !writer.Write() )
    {
    std::cerr << "Could not write: " << outfilename << std::endl;
    return 1;
    }

  return 0;
}

/*
 * (*) static type, means that extra DICOM information VR & VM are computed at compilation time.
 * The compiler is deducing those values from the template arguments of the class.
 */
```

It has a few header files that it is looking for namely gdcmreader, gdcmwriter and I want to figure out the compiler flags to use to be able to run this file.
I am doing  `g++ a.cpp -lgdcmCommon -lgdcmDICT`   but that gives me the error

```
a.cpp:18:24: fatal error: gdcmReader.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Can you please help me out? I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to figure out how to run this file.

Comment: `#include "myfile.h"` is not the same as `#include <myfile.h>`. Also, g++ needs to know where GDCM libs (`.so`) are.

Comment: I did changed all commas to < and > respectively.
 All the .a files are in the  /usr/local/lib

Comment: Still can't figure out how to use these.

Answer (score 1):

When using files that are in different locations of your "normal" files you must instruct the compiler and the linker how to find them.

Your code has a `#include <someFile.h>` command.

The `<>` usage means "in other path". The compiler already knows common "other paths" as for "stdio" for common libraries.

In case of "not normal", you can tell g++ where to find the headers by adding `-Imydir` to the command line (replace 'mydir' with the proper path)

For the libraries, static (.a) or dynamic (.so) the same history stands.

The `-Lmydir` tells g++ where to look for libraries.

Your command line may look like

```
g++ a.cpp -I/usr/include -L/usr/local/lib -lgdcmCommon -lgdcmDICT
```

Comment: I tried using that command too but it didn't work.
The output remains the same and yes I am replacing my dir with the directory

Comment: Find where GDCM headers and libs are. The replace the paths in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell how did you install gdcm library, I assume that using `apt` system. There are two types of libraries, "normal" and "developer" ones. To be able to compile your own software, you need the latter. So, for example in Ubuntu 16.04, type `apt-get install libgdcm2-dev`. Then all necessary headers will be installed in `/usr/include/gdcm-2.6`.